# Get frequencies of values within specific range

Tags: r, vector, range

i have the following data

```
data<-c(3,4,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,5)
lowerLimits<-c(2,4,6)
upperLimits<-c(4,6,8)
```

How can i count elements in data which are >= lowerLimits and < upperLimits. 
So the result should like this:

```
result<-c(1,6,3)
```

I'm sure this will be easy by using loops, but this can't be efficient. Does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: where do you get 1,6,3 from? I can't see any 1 anywhere except result

Comment: I wish I could just vote to close on the basis of the probability tha thtis has been asked and answered at least 5 times on SO.

Comment: @rafee there is 1 element which is in range [2;4[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply` and a little logical function:

```
myfun <- function(ll, ul) {
    sum(data >= ll & data < ul)
}

mapply(myfun, lowerLimits, upperLimits)
# [1] 1 6 3
```

Comment: Thnak you!! Works well

Answer (score 1):

A binary indexed tree or BIT does exactly what you are asking for -> [see this nice totorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees)

Answer (score 0):

```
> sapply(seq(length(lowerLimits)), function(x) sum(data > lowerLimits[x] & data <= upperLimits[x]))
[1] 3 6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your lower and upper limits are a continual range, you can also use `cut` and `table`.

```
> data <- c(3,4,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,5)
> breaks <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
> counts <- table(cut(data, breaks=breaks, right=FALSE))

[2,4) [4,6) [6,8) 
    1     6     3
```

Note `counts` will be a `table` object, so if you need a vector, you can just do `as.vector(counts)`.